# Multithreading using Executor service is processing sequentially instead of concurrent

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, soap, executorservice

I have the xml requests generated in one table. I need to invoke the external webservice by reading the requests from the table. I want to submit multiple requests at the same time using multithreading executor service. The code is calling the webservice sequentially instead of concurrent processing. Any suggestions would  be helpful.

### Below is the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.sql.Clob;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import org.apache.commons.io.input.ReaderInputStream;

import javax.xml.soap.*;

public class SoapClientSVAPI2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory= null;
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = null;
        Connection conn= null;
        Statement s = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        String soapEndpointUrl = "XXX";
        String reqid;
        Clob payload= null;


        try {

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        conn =  DriverManager.getConnection
              ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXX:1521:XXX", "XXX", "XX");
         s = conn.createStatement();

         // Create SOAP Connection
         soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
         soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

       String migTable = "SELECT req_id,payload,attr_9 FROM tableX WHERE ATTR_9 = \'READY\' ORDER BY dbms_random.value";
       s.execute(migTable);

       String updateTableSQL = "UPDATE tableX SET RESPONSE = ? , attr_9 = ? WHERE REQ_ID = ?";
       preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(updateTableSQL);

       ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();

       while((rs!=null) && (rs.next()))
       {
           payload = rs.getClob(2);
           reqid = rs.getString(1);

         final class CallWebService implements Callable<String[]> {

               String soapEndpointUrl = "xxx";
               String reqid;
               Connection conn1 = null;
               PreparedStatement prepstmt = null;
               SOAPConnection soapConn = null;
               Clob payload= null;

                  public CallWebService( String reqid, Clob payload, Connection conn1,PreparedStatement prepstmt,  SOAPConnection soapConn ) {
                       this.reqid = reqid;
                       this.payload = payload;
                       this.conn1 = conn1;
                       this.prepstmt = prepstmt;
                       this.soapConn = soapConn;
                   }

                  @Override
               public String[] call() throws Exception {

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
                String svresponse = "";

                try {

                     String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();

                     System.out.println("Reqid: "+reqid+ "Thread name:"+ threadName);

                       Reader ir = new BufferedReader(payload.getCharacterStream());
                       InputStream is = new ReaderInputStream(ir,"UTF-8");
                       SOAPMessage inpRequest = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null, is);


                       SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConn.call(inpRequest, soapEndpointUrl);

                       if (soapResponse != null)
                       {
                                baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                soapResponse.writeTo(baos); 
                                svresponse = baos.toString();
                       }

                     }

                   catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                       svresponse = "ERROR: " + e.getMessage();
                   }

                  finally 
                     {
                         if (baos != null) 
                         {
                             try 
                             {
                                 baos.close();
                             } 
                             catch (IOException ioe) 
                             {

                                ioe.printStackTrace();
                             }
                          }
                       }

                     return new String[] { reqid, svresponse};
              }
         };
     //calling webservice      
     if(reqid != null & !reqid.equals(""))
     {
           CallWebService cweb = new CallWebService(reqid,payload,conn,preparedStatement,soapConnection);
           Future<String[]> future = executor.submit(cweb);
           String response = "";
           String reqidout = "";
           String status = "FAILURE";
           try {
               // Wait 10s for response.
               reqidout = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)[0];
               response = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)[1];

           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               response = "InterruptedException";
               future.cancel(true);
           } catch (ExecutionException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               response = "ExecutionException";
               future.cancel(true);
           } catch (TimeoutException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               response = "TimeoutException";
               future.cancel(true);
           }

            if(response != null && response.indexOf("ReturnCode") > 0)
            {
                status = "SUCCESS";
            }

           preparedStatement.setString(1, response);
           preparedStatement.setString(2, status);
           preparedStatement.setString(3, reqidout);

           // execute update SQL statement
           preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

         }
       }

    }  

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("\nError occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server!\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {

            System.out.println("Time end"+new Date());

          executor.shutdown();
          try {
            executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

            if (soapConnection != null && conn != null)
            {
                try {
                    soapConnection.close();
                    s.close();
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SOAPException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is because you are submitting the job and making the main thread wait for 10 second timeout period before submitting the next job.

Use future.get() once you have finished submitting all your jobs.

My 2 cents worth, I would also strongly recommend refactoring your code to have single responsibility methods with less coupling (only the required method parameters).  For example, decouple reading from DB, calling webservice and inserting response into DB etc as separate methods. This should allow you to better find and resolve such sequencing problems.

Comment: Thanks Brahmam for your suggestions.

Comment: Hi Brahmam, i followed your suggestions and it worked for me.. Thanks once again !!